# Support vector regression prediction: issue with the output

Tags: r, regression, predictive-models, svm

I want to apply support vector regression (SVR) model parameters to a higher spatial scale using the `predict` function, but the results are wrong. Here is how the resulting raster is:
[image: svr_res]

The steps I followed were:

1. perform regression using the `svm` function at a coarser spatial scale
2. using the `predict` function and a fine resolution raster I produced the raster showing in the image above.

Here is the code:

```
library(e1071)
library(terra)
library(raster)

ntl = rast("path/ntl.tif") # coarse resolution raster
tirs = rast("path/tirs.tif") # fine resolution raster
tirs_res = resample(tirs, ntl, method = "bilinear")

a = c(ntl, tirs_res)

# Regression with SVM
modelsvm = svm(ntl ~ tirs, data = a)

# Predict using SVM regression
predYsvm = as.data.frame(predict(modelsvm, tirs))

# here I am just converting the result of the predict to a raster
tirsdf = as.data.frame(tirs, xy = TRUE)
svrpred = as.data.frame(cbind(tirsdf, as.data.frame(predYsvm)))
svr_pred = subset(svrpred, select = -tirs)
colnames(svr_pred)[3] = "tirs"
svr_pred <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(data = svr_pred, coords = cbind(svr_pred$x, svr_pred$y)) 
gridded(svr_pred) <- TRUE
svr_pred <- raster(svr_pred)
raster::crs(svr_pred) <- "EPSG:7767"
plot(svr_pred)
```

Any ideas why the resulting raster looks like this?

The data:

```
ntl = rast(ncols=11, nrows=21, nlyrs=1, xmin=581428.888, xmax=603703.888, ymin=1004925.5202, ymax=1047450.5202, names=c('ntl'), crs='EPSG:7767')

tirs = rast(ncols=48, nrows=93, nlyrs=1, xmin=582525, xmax=604125, ymin=1005525, ymax=1047375, names=c('tirs'), crs='EPSG:7767')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(terra)
library(raster)
library(e1071)

ntl = rast("path/ntl.tif")
tirs = rast("path/tirs.tif")
tirsres = resample(tirs, ntl, method = "bilinear")

s = c(ntl, tirsres)

m = svm(ntl~., data = s)
p = as.data.frame(predict(m, tirs))

df = as.data.frame(tirs, xy = TRUE)
df2 = as.data.frame(cbind(df, p))
df2 <- df2[-3]
colnames(df2)[3] = "tirs"
r <- rasterFromXYZ(df2)
plot(r)
```

[image: svr_pred]